# Using separate components in a linear mat-horizontal-stepper

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-material-stepper

In Angular, is it possible to have a linear stepper where the individual steps are separate components? For example:

```html
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear">
    <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup" label="Some Form">
        <first-component></first-component>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup" label="Another Form">
        <second-component></second-component>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="thirdFormGroup" label="Review">
        <third-component></third-component>
    </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

When I try this, I receive the following error upon hitting the `matStepperNext` button:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined`.

Comment: Can we see your component.ts code? My guess is that one or more of your stepcontrol variables is undefined in the component.

Comment: @BrianWright So I tried to put together a minimal example on plnkr, but I must have screwed something up, because it tells me it can't find one of the components... https://embed.plnkr.co/5Yx4RTIrIHklRtH5rJHO/ (Totally different than the issue I'm talking about above).

Comment: No worries, see my answer below. Also, check this out: https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: @BrianWright Thanks! Stackblitz is way easier than plnkr. So, I've made the following example. I'm actually getting a separate issue - where the `linear` property `mat-horizontal-stepper` isn't being enforced. It's allowing you to skip ahead to a subsequent step even though the form isn't valid. However, I suspect that if that weren't the case, you'd see the same issue (the error when hitting the Next button). Here's the example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fjhcgm

Comment: Sure thing! Yeah this is much better. I'll take a look a little later, unless someone beats me to it!

Comment: I have the same scenario. (y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Improving on @eliran-eliassy answer and @christian-steinmeyer question.

**Parent.Component.ts**

```
  export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  isLinear = true;
  companyInfo: FormGroup;

  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.companyInfo = this._formBuilder.group({
    });

  }

}
```

**Parent.Component.html**

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear" #stepper>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="companyInfo">
        <form [formGroup]="companyInfo">
            <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your name</ng-template>
            <app-company-info></app-company-info>
        </form>
        <div>
            <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
        </div>
    </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

**Child.Component.ts** -> this is the sub-form

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;
  subForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(
    private ctrlContainer: FormGroupDirective,
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subForm = this.fb.group({
      companyName: [null, [Validators.required]],
      numOfEmployees: [null, [Validators.required]]
    });
    
    this.form = this.ctrlContainer.form;
    this.form.addControl("company", this.subForm);
  }
}
```

**Child.Component.html**

```
<div [formGroup]="subForm">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <input matInput placeholder="Your Company Name" formControlName="companyName">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

See this solution on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-576er7?file=src/app/company-info/company-info.component.html)

Answer (score 8):

You can use **sub-forms** to resolve it.
I actually gave a talk a few months ago in Angular-UP conference about it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sb7tgsNF2Jk

The idea, in general, is to create the form in the child component, inject the controlContainer using DI and setting the local form to be the controlContainer form.

**Child Component:**

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'app-company-info',
  templateUrl: './company-info.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./company-info.component.scss'],
  viewProviders: [{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: FormGroupDirective }]
})
export class CompanyInfoComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;
  constructor(
    private ctrlContainer: FormGroupDirective,
    private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.form = this.ctrlContainer.form;

    this.form.addControl('company',
      this.fb.group({
        'companyName': this.fb.control(null, [Validators.required]),
        'numOfEmployees': this.fb.control(null, [Validators.required])});

  }

}
```

**Parent Component (html):**

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear" #stepper>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="companyInfo">
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your name</ng-template>

    <form [formGroup]="companyInfo">
      <app-company-info></app-company-info>
    </form>

    <div>
      <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
    </div>
  </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

**Parent Component (ts):**

```
export class WizardComponent implements OnInit {

  isLinear = true;
  companyInfo: FormGroup;

  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.companyInfo = this._formBuilder.group({
    });

  }

}
```

Comment: Could you provide a working example? I've prepared this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zhvrs5?file=src/app/app.module.ts), so it should be quick :)

Comment: Improves on both answers using the subform. This is the example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-576er7?file=src/app/company-info/company-info.component.html)

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solution that work for me.

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="true" #stepper>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="selectAdvType">
    <ng-template matStepLabel>
      <div class="text-center">
        <mat-icon>queue_play_next</mat-icon><br /><span>Select Adv Type</span>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
    <app-advertisement-type></app-advertisement-type>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="selectAdvType">
    <ng-template matStepLabel>
      <div class="text-center">
        <mat-icon>directions_car</mat-icon><br /><span>Select Car</span>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
    <app-select-car-adv></app-select-car-adv>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step>
    <ng-template matStepLabel>
      <div class="text-center">
        <mat-icon>description</mat-icon><br /><span>Select Features</span>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
    <div>
      <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
      <button mat-button (click)="stepper.reset()">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

**Parent Ts file**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-customer.create.advertisement',
  templateUrl: './customer.create.advertisement.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer.create.advertisement.component.scss']
})
export class CustomerCreateAdvertisementComponent implements OnInit {
  isLinear = false;
  selectAdvType: FormGroup;
  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectAdvType = this._formBuilder.group({
      firstCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
}
```

**Child component**

```
<form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your name</ng-template>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Last name, First name" formControlName="firstCtrl" required>
    </mat-form-field>
    <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
    </div>
</form>


@Component({
  selector: 'app-advertisement-type',
  templateUrl: './advertisement-type.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./advertisement-type.component.scss']
})
export class AdvertisementTypeComponent implements OnInit {
  firstFormGroup: FormGroup;
  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      firstCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Why we need to define two times(parent and child component ts file) the below form builder 'firstCtrl: ['', Validators.required]'. Suppose if i have 10 items in the child element form, Does it configure in the parent component also?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I see a few issues:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear">
  <mat-step [stepControl]="foodFormGroup">
    <food-selection></food-selection>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="pieFormGroup">
    <pie-selection></pie-selection>
  </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

**foodFormGroup** and **pieFormGroup** need to be defined in your **tough-choice.component.ts** file (Which, btw is misspelled in your example code)

**Here's an example** (from the docs) of how this might look:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

/**
 * @title Stepper overview
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'stepper-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'stepper-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['stepper-overview-example.css']
})
export class StepperOverviewExample {
  isLinear = false;
  firstFormGroup: FormGroup;
  secondFormGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      firstCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });
    this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      secondCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
}
```

Also, I don't see a module.ts file in your example. That's where you would want to import your @angular/material modules, not in the component files.

I'd suggest just giving the Angular Material documentation a once-over.
https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the heads-up on the typo, that was driving me up a wall. I responded to your comment on the main post with a stackblitz demo.